# Telethon выводит другой id

Tags: python, telethon

Есть код:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    print(chat)
```

Он выводит это:

```
Channel(id=1799752035, .................
```

Но на самом деле id канала другой:

```
-1001799752035
```

Почему так?

Comment: Замечаете, что концы айдишников совпадают?)

Comment: да заметил просто интересно было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому что `-100` - префикс, а питон не использует префикс при выводе ID канала. Чтобы перевести из питоновского в "настоящий" ID, добавьте префикс `-100`.

---

Важно знать, что "настоящие" идентификаторы каналов всегда отрицательные и длиной в 13 символов! В начале *всегда* находится префикс `-100`